# Javascript function not stopping submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
             function checkdates()
             {
                    var startdate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["startdate"].value;
                    var enddate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["enddate"].value;
                    if (Date.parse(startdate) > Date.parse(enddate))
                        {
                            alert("The End Date can not be before the Start Date")
                            return false;
                        }

             }
```

I have this javascript function which is check two inputted dates, one of which is a holiday start date and the other is the end date. If the user selects an end date that is before the start date, the alert pops up, but it submits the form?

```
<form name="frmHolidayRequest" action="HomePage.asp" onsubmit="return InputBoxValidation() || checkdates() || samedates()" method="post">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="startdate" readonly="true" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="enddate" readonly="true" />
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: is this being called from an `onsubmit` handler?

Comment: Yes. onsubmit="return checkdates()" @Greg

Comment: does the conditional return true?

Comment: If the alert shows then the above code is fine.  Can you edit the question and include where you attach the function to the submit event?  (I know you've posted a bit of it above, but there's got to be something wrong with that so we need to see more)

Comment: the onsubmit in which tag is?

Comment: What do `InputBoxValidation()` and `samedates()` return? If either result in `true` or a *truthy* value, they'll overrule a `false` from `checkdates()` with `||` between them.

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  You must be returning `true` from one of the other functions.  Just put a `console.log` or `alert` in them to find out what's going wrong.  Ideally, just put all your validation into 1 function and call that on submit.

Comment: Thanks, ive managed to get it working now. Thanks for the help :) @Archer

Comment: No worries.  Using the `event.preventDefault()` approach means just calling the functions will stop the form submitting (when relevant), regardless of the results of the others, so it's a more robust approach.  Like I said, just do all your validation in the one function and you're laughing.  Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the inline submit handler and bind the submit event using jQuery's .ON method.

Defined the checkdates function.

```
function checkdates() {
    var startdate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["startdate"].value,
        enddate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["enddate"].value;

    if (Date.parse(startdate) > Date.parse(enddate)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#YOURFORMID').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // If your function returns true, submit the form. 
        if (checkdates()) {
            $(this).submit();
        // If it returns false. Throw your alert.   
        } else {
            alert("The End Date can not be before the Start Date");
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your approach is wrong. You need a preventdefault.

Example with jQuery in your javascript:

And remove the onsubmit=yourfunction, cus jquery will intercept the original submit.

```
$("[name='frmHolidayRequest']").submit(function(event){

    var startdate = $("[name='startdate']").val(); // if you used Name , if u id it's $("#startdate").val(); 
    var enddate = $("[name='enddate']").val();
    if (Date.parse(startdate) > Date.parse(enddate))
       {           
         event.preventDefault();  
         alert("The End Date can not be before the Start Date");
       }
  });
```

EDIT: You are using names, not id I see for the form name, so my previous code was wrong^^

Answer (score 1):

Alert does not stop submitting the form. If you want to stop submitting when you go in to the If statement, please try:

```
function checkdates(e)
             {
                    var startdate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["startdate"].value;
                    var enddate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["enddate"].value;
                    if (Date.parse(startdate) > Date.parse(enddate))
                        {

                            alert("The End Date can not be before the Start Date")
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the alert is blocking the thread and the result from your checkdates() is timeing out. You should prevent the default behavior before you pop up your alert box.

Important: put the preventDefault *before* your alert

```
function checkdates(evt)
{
    var startdate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["startdate"].value;
    var enddate = document.forms["frmHolidayRequest"]["enddate"].value;
    if (Date.parse(startdate) > Date.parse(enddate))
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert("The End Date can not be before the Start Date")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no "timing out". Yes, preventDefault will stop the form from submitting, but the preventDefault is hiding the error in the OPs code.

Comment: What??? This makes 0 sense.  Blocking will stop the form submitting so returning false would be enough to stop it (if it weren't for the other function calls in the event handler).  Also, there has been no mention of passing the event object into the function so that could not possibly work.  :confused:

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is

```
return InputBoxValidation() || checkdates() || samedates()
```

It says return true if any of these are true. You should be using AND, not OR

```
onsubmit="return return (InputBoxValidation() && checkdates() && samedates());"
```

or

```
function validateAll() {
    var testA = InputBoxValidation();
    var testB = checkdates();
    var testC = samedates();
    return testA && testB && testC;
}
```

and

```
onsubmit="return validateAll();"
```

Comment: That does not even alert then?

Comment: Why would it not alert? in the first case, if `InputBoxValidation` is not true than the others will not run. Seconds case all will run.